# Configure maven repository timeout

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a missing jar in one public repository. When I open it in web browser I get

{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "{\"error\":\"not found\"}"
  } ]
}

How I can configure maven to skip the repository if jar file is missing?
Is there any configuration for timeout?

Comment: But how can your build work if you can't download the necessary dependencies?

Comment: Any solution for this?